# How can call file like ipn in ARB subscription when deduct payment. in Authorized .net?

Tags: php, authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

I have many subscription in Auth.net all the subscription works as the 30 day time duration and that all the run for the 60 months.

I have several operation such as the email and update my db related and amount change kind of many operation I have to perform when any subscription is made.

Currently I am made it for cron job but there was very long and complex process to do code.

So research on that I found the auth.net something use like the Silent post url.

but I have tried in my sandbox account but it not works. and I am not sure about that this is works when subscription deduct money on the card?

**What is silent post url and it's works or not ?**

Comment: Are you asking if Silent Post will tell you when a subscription payment is made?

Comment: @john i want make sure about the Silent Post Url is surely call when subscription payment is made every time. if yes then i make code on that file. because minimum auth.net recurring payment takes 7 day. so i am not able to test it. so if anybody is know that and sure for that that file run when subscription payment made.

Comment: Silent Post is definitely sent for all subscription payments

Comment: Thanks @John Have you any idea it's works in sandbox test account or not because i tried in my test account but it not worked ?

Comment: Sandbox accounts do not process subscriptions so you can only see work in production

Comment: OK Thanks @John for the information.

Comment: @YagnikDetroja The sandbox does actually process ARB subscriptions according to the schedule you created.  Subscriptions begin processing at approximately 2am the next morning.  If you're not being notified by silent post, it may be an issue with how that is configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am posting an answer on basis of the comments and research.**

IPN and silent post URL are same things.

- Silent post URL are not working on test account you need to use live
  account necessary.
- Silent post URL are always call when payment deduct. that doesn't
  matter that payment are for the ARB or simple.
- You can enter only one silent post URL they are use that url every payment of
  the auth.net
- payment deduct by auth.net next approx 2 am at the morning so you can
  use cron job also.

**Silent Post Url how to test.**

[Testing Silent Post with Authorize.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413710/testing-silent-post-with-authorize-net)

```
<form action="http://www.yourdomain.com/silent-post.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="x_response_code" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_response_subcode" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_response_reason_code" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_response_reason_text" value="This transaction has been approved."/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_auth_code" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_avs_code" value="P"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_trans_id" value="1821199455"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_invoice_num" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_description" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_amount" value="9.95"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_method" value="CC"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_type" value="auth_capture"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_cust_id" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_first_name" value="John"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_last_name" value="Smith"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_company" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_address" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_city" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_state" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_zip" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_country" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_phone" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_fax" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_email" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_ship_to_first_name" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_ship_to_last_name" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_ship_to_company" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_ship_to_address" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_ship_to_city" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_ship_to_state" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_ship_to_zip" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_ship_to_country" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_tax" value="0.0000"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_duty" value="0.0000"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_freight" value="0.0000"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_tax_exempt" value="FALSE"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_po_num" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_MD5_Hash" value="A375D35004547A91EE3B7AFA40B1E727"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_cavv_response" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_test_request" value="false"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_subscription_id" value="365314"/>
<input type="hidden" name="x_subscription_paynum" value="1"/>
<input type="submit"/>
```

This kind of the post name you can get in the your silent post file.

description for test:-

- make one form on the your directory of the project and put above
  code.
- change action url of the form where is actually your Silent post Url
  file there you need to code in future for the live.
- there you can print the data how you receive and get name of the post
  data.

  ```
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_REQUEST);
  echo "</pre>";
  die();
  ```
- print array and see the testing data.

Hope that answer will help to understand silent post url.

Thanks.